# Applescript perform action AXShowMenu

Tags: applescript, imessage, uiaccessibility

I've looked everywhere for an answer but can't find anything on this. When I run this code the action AXShowMenu executes correctly. But the script continues to run for a few seconds and throws the error:

"action "AXShowMenu" of menu button of text field of scroll area 3 of splitter group 1 of window "Messages" of process "Messages" doesn’t understand the “perform” message."

Am I missing something painfully obvious here? How can I get Applescript to move on after it executes the AXShowMenu action?

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Messages"
            perform action "AXShowMenu" of menu button of text field of scroll area 3 of splitter group 1 of window "Messages"
    end tell
end tell
```

[AXShowMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcaWZ.png)

This is the link to the menu i'm trying to access. The element can be created if you create a new message and input some text in the text field.

Comment: I went ahead and added it in the description. I actually solved the issue with: "tell menu button 1 of text field 1 of scroll area 3 of splitter group 1 of window "Messages" to perform action 1" but this takes 5+ seconds to execute for some reason.

Comment: Are you wanting to access the menu item to _Create New Contact..._ that appears in that popup menu ?  If that's the case, would it be easier if you accessed the menu item from the main menu bar instead, which negates the need to go via the popup menu ?

Comment: I'm actually trying determine if the number is an imessage or text message by referencing the value of the first menu item which just so happens to be "Text Message" in this case. Unfortunately the lengthy delay I'm getting for some reason is slowing the script down immensely.

Comment: Taking your code at face value, have you tried adding the indexes to the last two elements of the chain: i.e., `perform action "AXShowMenu" of menu button 1 of text field 1 of...`. I'm surprised your code works at all (apparently AppleScript can sometimes figure out indexes by context) but it's better to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Having established your end goal is to determine whether the number entered into the `To:` field in the *Messages* app operates under the iMessage service or the SMS service, you could try using properties of the `buddies` and `services` objects to determine whether they can be used to discriminate effectively between the types of numbers.

As I don't have an iPhone, I lack SMS capability from my *Messages* app.  However, what I've observed when I enter some random number is that it will be categorised by the *Messages* app into the type of service that, I assume, will be the most appropriate for the nature of the number:

```
use application "Messages"

service type of services of buddy "12343" = iMessage
```

For me, this returns `true`, simply because `iMessage` is the only active service type that operates in my *Messages* app.  However, this response is inline with what appears in the popup menu within the app.

So, assuming the logic follows, I would hope that you could either make use of those two lines as they are, swapping out the number as needed, and working off a value that will either be `true` or `false`; or perhaps first working out if your *Messages* app has a "default" service into which it will categorise numbers of uncertain nature.  My guess is that it will favour "SMS" rather than iMessage given both available services to choose from, in which case the following script might be more suitable:

```
use application "Messages"

name of service of buddy "12343" = "SMS"
```

---

**NB:**  It's possible that different locales use different service names, and what AppleScript on a British system refers to as `service "SMS"` might be `service "Text Message"` on a US system, or wherever you're located.

You can easily perform a quick initial check on the names of each *Messages* `service` by running `tell application "Messages" to get the name of every service`.  The list will contain 4 or 5 potential services, but it'll be clear which applies to text messaging, and slightly ambiguous but eventually apparent which applies to iMessaging.

Comment: Great idea! Although this is still presenting me with a problem. No matter which buddy text is entered the statement = iMessage is true. Even if the buddy service is actually SMS.

Comment: Then instead of using `service type`, use the `name of service` as per my second code snippet?  Tell me how that works out.

Comment: That method works well for buddies that are established in your chat history but it seems to add two buddies to the buddy list whenever a new recipient is added. One with SMS and one with the iMessage service. So I can never tell which is the correct one. I discovered this by using: tell application "Messages" to get the name of every service of buddy. 2 buddies with the same name and different services were listed there.

Comment: Sorry it didn’t work out as planned.  What you described feels like a bug to me.  I suppose you could report it to Apple, but I doubt they’ll care.